Securing My AWS Endpoints exposed using ALB: AWS Best Practices
I have an application in AWS, I'm using Fargate (ECS) or you can think in EC2, the idea is the same.
In front of it, I have a Loadbalance receiving 443 and my port but both in HTTPS and with my domains exposed to it by route53.
My front end is static HTML in Cloudfront (s3), and I'm using JavaScript to access my endpoints.
I have an Authorization process for my endpoints but I'm receiving some GET requests to endpoints I don't have, it is a kind of an attack I don't know how to prevent.
What should I do to block it before receiving it in my app? And how?
I don't know if using APIGateway is the solution or if another approach is necessary.

To strengthen your application security, I would suggest using CloudFront for your Backend (ECS services exposed through ALB) as well.
CloudFront will help you cache content and distribute it closer to users for faster delivery. It will also offer security features like HTTPS termination and custom policies. And you can restrict your ALB Security Group to only allow traffic from CloudFront IPs.
In addition, you can also enable the rate limit on CloudFront using WAF.  While it's not strictly necessary, I think it will help you achieve your goals,
WAF rate limits will track incoming requests and identify potential abuse patterns. It can also block suspicious IP addresses exceeding request limits to safeguard your service.

It does not work, cloudfront delivery HTML files, these files contain javascript running in javascript and several IPs.
Block IP is fine, but should block always I get suspicious incomming.

What you are looking for is WAF to track and block the traffic there are many more rulesets you can check on it. The reason behind suggesting CloudFront was to avoid hitting the origin for every request.
